# Generate a list of intersected layers QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-query

Apologies, im very new to QGIS and there's a chance what I'm asking for isn't actually what I require. Let me explain.

I'm working with a project with multiple layers. I have a layer (let's call it layer 1) with multiple polygons outlining site boundaries. What I would like to know is if it is possible for QGIS to generate a list of all the layers that a specific polygon in layer 1 intersects with?

I know how to use a spatial query but all this does is highlight a load of polygons that intersect with a particular layer.

Comment: Is it just one polygon you want? Or do you want to work out the intersections for all of the polygons on layer 1? Do you want these intersections added as attributes to layer 1 or a derivative or do you actually just want a non-geometry table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this task is to merge all layers (using saga merge) you want to intersect 1 layer with and then make normal Spatial query.

Saga Merge is inside Processing -> Toolbox -> Saga -> Merge vector layers. Just add source layer information after merge.

[image: Saga merge]

Comment: Ah okay, so then use the usual spatial query with the layer and the merged ones?

Comment: yep :) inside your merge layer you will have new column with all names of your polygons. After spatial query you will have selected names :)

Comment: Don't suppose there's a way to access the source information in a spatialite query? It would help with another question I've asked [gis.stackexchange.com/q/225232/64402](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/225232/64402) and give scope for using a virtual layer as a solution

Comment: Your welcome ;) Is always nice to share knowledge :)

Comment: I've just tried Processing -> Toolbox -> Saga -> Merge vector layers and the source attribute in the result are just numbers such as 1485254891.233. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First thought is  to select the specific polygon, convert that to a new layer, then use that new layer for the spatial query