# QGIS combine attribute table of different layers

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

Is there a way to create a single table that contains multiple layers with all of their attributes? I have multiple layers that have the same feature options (but with different values). I basically want to add rows onto the table that come from different layers. Can this be done? I have it so my individual layer attributes automatically update as changes are made to the layer, and I would like automatic updates to show up in this new combined table as well. I have example attribute tables of two of my layers below. [image]

[image]

Comment: did you try to merge the layers together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a virtual layer with an SQL request, as the table from this layer will come from a request from your original table it will reflect any change made on the original layer.

For creating it you could try the code [from this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225232/how-to-include-layer-names-when-unioning-in-virtual-layers)